# Error message deleting the last row of a section using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've got an `UITableView` that uses an `NSFetchedResultsController` as it's data source. I use one of the fields for my sections. I enabled row deletion (using the swipe gesture). Works just fine.

The problem comes up when I delete the last row of a section. It does not crash on me but the console shows the following message:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section
>   after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in
>   that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows
>   inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus
>   or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved
>   in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

This is all pretty basic stuff:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [[self tableView] beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        …
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                    atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
        …
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [[self tableView] endUpdates];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source            
        FHClass *foo = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];;
        [[self managedObjectContext] deleteObject:meal];
        [self saveContext];
    }  
}
```

If I check `-numberOfRowsInSection:` I see that the number is steadily decreasing when deleting rows. Even to the point where it says `0`.

What did I miss? Any hints? Stupid mistake on my part? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement `controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:` to deal with section changes and then request the table view to `deleteSections:`.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thanks a lot!